# Notepad++ Regex Help in cleaning up file

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

I've got a csv file (the column separator is "<;>" ,the text delimiter is the double quote and the row separator "crlf") of more than 18000 lines.

However,many of the data contained within the text separator do contain "crlf" , this create issue when trying to import or validate the file structure as well as other one.

```
"2"<;>"1305767"<;>"MSCUFH613249 [CRLF] 199PACKAGES"<;>""<;>"Y"[CRLF]
```

I've tried the suggestions found on  the following posts to no avail.

1. [Replace charaters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493861/seeking-regex-in-notepad-to-search-and-replace-crlf-between-two-quotation-mark/14495204#14495204)
2. [Replace Carriage Return](https://superuser.com/questions/545461/replace-carriage-return-and-line-feed-in-notepad)

I've been able using Notepad++ to remove the Carriage return with the Find\Replace with the Wrap Around and Extented options On. However this also replace the row delimiter at the end of the line.

I would like to replace all "\r\n" or CRLF within any text delimiters("") with a blank space.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help:

```
\n(?!")|\r(?!")|\r\n(?!")
```

Comment: Care to expand on that for the benefit of us non-regular expression buffs?

Comment: Thanks @Maze Oslo; This will find both "CrLf" ,"Lf" and "Cr"  between the double quote ("") text delimiters.
 I've coupled it with the find and replace. In the find i inserted the above reg-ex and in replace a blank space with the "Wrap around" and "Regular Expression" ON.

Comment: This renders the remaining EOL characters in the Unix/OSX format. You may want to use the EOL Conversion utility in the edit menu to swap back to Windows Format when you're done.

Comment: Thanks @Jason ,I used find "\s\n(?!" )" and replace with "\r\n"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex search-&-replace-s:

1. Search-&-replace `[CRLF]` within `"`...`"` with a simple white space:

   Find: `"([^"]*)\r\n([^"]*)"`

   Replace: `"$1 $2"`
2. If required, search-&-replace `<;>` with an appropriate separator, say, `,`:

   Find: `<;>`

   Replace: `,`

**Example:**

Input:

```
"2"<;>"1305767"<;>"MSCUFH613249 
 199PACKAGES"<;>""<;>"Y"
```

Output:

After step-1:

```
"2"<;>"1305767"<;>"MSCUFH613249   199PACKAGES<;>""<;>"Y"
```

After step-2:

```
"2","1305767","MSCUFH613249   199PACKAGES,"","Y"
```

Comment: Thanks @Roney, however this make the next line being added to first one.